# Detecting by how much user has scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image pop-up ability on my website, in order to show users the full resolution picture when they click on a smaller version on the page.

This is the current `CSS` that positions it:

```
div#enlargedImgWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 55px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The problem now is that if I click on an image further down the page, the window still appears in the top left corner of the page, where I can't see it until I scroll back up. I need it to appear relative to the window, whatever its current position relative to the document is.

**Note:** I don't want to use `position: fixed;` as some images might be taller than the screen, so I want users to be able to scroll along the image as well.

My idea was to use JS to change the `top` value:

```
var scrollValue = ???;
document.getElementById('enlargedImgWrapper').style.top = scrollValue+30 + 'px';
```

How can I detect by how much the user has scrolled down the page (`var scrollValue`)?
Or is there a 'better' way to do this?

**Edit:** if possible I would like to do this without jQuery.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Pure JavaScript uses `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`:

```
var scrollLeft = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop

`jQuery` version:

```
var scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft() ;
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() ;
```

What you need is this:

```
document.getElementById('enlargedImgWrapper').style.top = (scrollTop+30) + 'px';
```

Comment: Why not `window.scrollY` like in [this MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event#examples)?

Comment: @LuisAFK: You can certainly use `window.scrollY`, but `scrollY` is only available on the window interface, while `scrollTop` is available on *any* element. OP gave the most general answer possible.

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById('enlargedImgWrapper').scrollTop;
```

**MDN**

> This property's value equals the current vertical offset of the
> content within the scrollable range. Although you can set this
> property to any value, if you assign a value less than 0, the property
> is set to 0. If you assign a value greater than the maximum value, the
> property is set to the maximum value.
>
> You can set this property inline, but the results might be
> inconsistent while the document is loading.

[scrollTop property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I think you misunderstood `element.scrollTop`. It returns by how much the content within `element` was scrolled, not by how much `element` has moved off the screen... Thanks anyway!

Comment: However, we can use `window.scrollTop` instead!

Comment: `window.scrollTop` is undifined for me

Answer (score 1):

In 2024 use `scrollY` and `scrollX`. As `pageYOffset` and `pageXOffset` are depriciated. Browser support: [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=scrolly)

```
const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
const scrollLeft = window.scrollX;
```

So it will be:

```
document.getElementById('enlargedImgWrapper').style.top = window.scrollY + 30 + 'px';
```