# Issue with autofocus attribute and history navigation

Tags: html, usability, autofocus

I have a page where a search field is placed in the header. This input uses the `autofocus` attribute to automatically place the focus into the field so that users can start searching right away:

```
<html>
  <head><title>autofocus issue</title></head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <form method="post">
        <input name="search" autofocus />
      </form>
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>Lots of contents here, so that the next link
         can only be reached by scrolling down ...</p>
      <a href="http://link.to/some/page">Go somewhere</a>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

While this works fine there is a problem when going forth and back in history. If the user scrolls down my page and clicks on a link and then goes back again (using browser history), my original page scrolls to the top where the search input is located.

This is a usability flaw because the scroll position shouldn't change when going back in history. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the HTML `autofocus` attribute you would want to check with JS if the user navigated to your page via the back button. Then only if they did NOT, you would call `searchField.focus()`.

The problem is, I see no direct way to [detect if the user clicked the “back” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008806/how-to-detect-if-the-user-clicked-the-back-button). You could however, try [getting the scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373741/detecting-by-how-much-user-has-scrolled), and call `.focus()` only if scrolled 0px:

```
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
if (scrollTop === 0) {
    searchField.focus();
}
```