# Detecting how much user has scrolled in BrowserView - Electron

Tags: scroll, electron, scrollbar

I need to detect how much the user has scrolled on the webpage rendered with **BrowserView** in Electron

```
view.webContents.on('input-event', (event, input) => {
      if (input.type === 'gestureScrollEnd') {
          console.log("viewManager-wiew.webContents.on('input-event')-input: ", input)
      }
  })
```

I actually get the `gestureScrollEnd` inputEvent :

```
viewManager-wiew.webContents.on('input-event')-input:  { type: 'gestureScrollEnd', 
modifiers: [], _modifiers: 0 }
```

I tried to detect the scrolling amount with `window.scrollTop`, `document.scrollTop` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` :

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("window.scrollTop: ", window.scrollTop)
    console.log("document.body.scrollTop: ", document.body.scrollTop)
     console.log("document.documentElement.scrollTop: ", document.documentElement.scrollTop)   
}, 5)
clearTimeout()
```

But, when scrolling within the webpage rendered by BrowserView I do not get the scrolling amount:

[image]

As far as I know, the only methods to detect how much the user has scrolled, use `window` and `document` `scrollTop` : [Detecting by how much user has scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373741/detecting-by-how-much-user-has-scrolled?rq=3)

But `window` and `document` are not accessible within `webContents`

How to do that?

Update 1)

I tried to execute Javascript within BrowserView's webContents, but, may be I'm doing something wrong, because it does not produce any output:

```
  let scrollTop = 0

  view.webContents.on('input-event', (event, input) => {
      if (input.type === 'gestureScrollEnd') {
          console.log("viewManager-wiew.webContents.on('input-event')-input: ", input)
          // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373741/detecting-by-how-much-user-has-scrolled?rq=3

          view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`console.log("viewManager-input-event-document.body.scrollTop: ", document.body.scrollTop)`)

          view.webContents.executeJavaScript(`scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop`)

          view.webContents.send("get-scroll-amount", {
              viewId: id,
              scroll_amount: scrollTop,
          })

      }
  })
```

And in the rendering page:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        window.api.electronIpcOn("get-scroll-amount", (event, args) => {
            console.log("App_S-get-scroll-amount- args: ", args)
        })
    },[])
```

But, I do not get any output

Comment: what about use window and document scrollTop and send it via ipcRenderer and IpcMain?

Comment: Hi @YAGOUBIA.E.K ! Already tried it. I updated my post above with the output

Comment: you can't execute JS in the webcontents to get that info? (not saying it's the best way, but an idea)

Comment: @pushkin I tried with ` view.webContents.executeJavaScript` but I don't get any output. May be I'm doing something wrong (I updated my post above)

Comment: I believe you want to do something like: `const scrollTop = await view.webContents.executeJavaScript("document.body.scrollTop")`